# C# - Capturing Network Traffic

Tags: c#, networking

I'm interested in capturing network traffic from a specific computer. I am only interested in capturing traffic from the computer that my application is installed on (like Fiddler). Like Fiddler, I want to in particular capture the information shown in the "Web Sessions" portion (ID#, Http Status Code, Protocol, Host, Url, Body size, Content-Type and Process.

While I'm very knowledgable in C#. I have no idea how to actually capture network traffic like this. Can somebody please point me in some sort of direction.

Thank you so much!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CSNetworkSniffer.aspx

Comment: Are you looking for something to integrate into your application, or a stand-alone application that runs alongside your app on the client that will capture traffic?

Comment: I thought the process of logging a port might be as easy as saying `new Port(portNumber).StartLogging(new Logger())`. But after Googling for almost 2 days, I found that this realm of coding is still wild :D.

Answer (score 6):

**NOTE:** I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for in terms of a stand-alone application or something to integrate into your application, but my answer will assume you're looking for something to integrate into your app.  If not, I'll delete this.

If you're looking for something to integrate into your application that you can essentially enable or disable, you should take a look at [FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Core/), which is the core functionality that Fiddler uses but can be integrated into stand-alone .NET apps.

The FiddlerCore wiki is [here](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore), and it describes the usage pretty well.  The sample app is also a good description on how to use FiddlerCore.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

winpcap or one of its .net wrappers is your best option. It is very well documented. If you are doing this in mono, you will need to use libpcap on unix machines. The api's are identical.